# Sign my android app when building with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, signing

I just converted my Eclipse project to an Android Studio project.

One of the very important step in the building/running process is to sign the apk.
So I used the "generate signed apk" from the build menu and it worked fine.

Now, I just want that when I run the app on the USB device, the signing is done automatically. [The Android Studio page](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) state that it's possible using the "signing" tabs in the module settings but this tabs doesn't exist!! See the picture below:

[image]

I have the latest version of Android Studio, so I guess this feature moved somewhere else but I can't find it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu is under File > Project Structure. Then select your module from the list on the left, switch to the signing tab, and add your signing information.

This will make two changes to your build.gradle:

First, it will add a `signingConfigs {}` section that looks something like this-

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("your.keystore")
        storePassword 'mySecreKystorePassword'
        keyAlias 'myKeyAlias'
        keyPassword 'mySecretKeyPassword'
    }
}
```

Second, it will configure your buildTypes to use this signing config like so-

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was doing, but there is not signing tab! Could it be because I imported from a Maven project? Where is this build.gradle file?

Comment: Are you sure you are running Android Studio 1.0 or higher? The build.gradle should be in your module's root directory.

Comment: I'm using version 1.0.2, freshly downloaded and updated. Could it be because I imported a Maven project? I can't find a gradle file.

Comment: When you go to File > Import Project and try to import a Maven project, it should try to generate a build.gradle for you. If you can't find one, it sounds like it didn't import properly. I would try importing again.

Comment: yeah it seems the import didn't go well. In one way, it only use Gradle and forget about maven and it's not able to compile.The other way, it use maven but I can't use anything related to gradle...

Answer (score 0):

Usually there're good reasons to have separate debug and production builds (e.g. separate API endpoint, separate API KEYS on tracking, faster building times), so I'll leave a question here for you: Why do you want to debug using a signed (a.k.a. production) build?

on the other hand, to answer your question, there's an easy way to switch which build variant that will be used when you hit the `play` button on AndroidStudio.

On the several panels around the border there's one named `BuildVariants` with a little Android icon. Over there's a drop-down menu where you can change to use debug or release build variant.

Comment: The reason why we need to sign even in debug is because the android box is not rooted. It will not allow to install the application if it's not signed.

Comment: there's no need to root a device to install an app from USB. Just enable the option on `Settings -> Security -> Unknown Source`, also the installation during development via Android Studio doesn't need that, you only need the developer options enabled `Settings -> Developer Options -> USB Debugging`

Comment: After verification, we discover that the reason why we need to sign the app is because we use "root" user. We have a special box made for us and the manufacturer give us the key to sign like them to use root (need some special access that only root is able to access).